# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl' even thoug I had downloaded it I am getting this error

Tags: python

"Requirement already satisfied: openpyxl in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: et-xmlfile in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
openpyxl) (1.1.0)"

Comment: Is the environment which raises the ImportError the *same* environment into which the package was installed?  (My presumption would be,  no.). Dig a bit deeper.

Comment: Are you running your code in the environment, where you installed the openpyxl?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things, you can try:

1. Restart your code-editor, sometimes, they have to restart to get all libraries after a new download.
2. If you are working with virtualenv, make sure you are using the same env where you have installed it.